# "Server response (401): You must login to access this feature" when registering package on pypi

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, pypi

I am trying to register a package on pyPI. After creating a .pypirc that looks like

```
[distutils] # this tells distutils what package indexes you can push to
index-servers =
  pypi
  pypitest

[pypi]
repository: https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username: "amfarrell"
password: "I dont post my passphrase publicly"

[pypitest]
repository: https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username: "amfarrell"
password: "I dont post my passphrase publicly"
```

I run `python setup.py register -r pypitest` and I get an error that ends in "Server response (401): You must login to access this feature". How do I login to pypi from the terminal?

I also get the error "Upload failed (401): You must be identified to edit package information" when I run `python setup.py sdist upload`.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the PyPI test server *at all*?

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, and the issue was that I had no account at the PyPI test server - they use a different user DB so you need to sign up there as well as the main server.

Comment: Yes, this happened to me too, the url to register for the test repository is: https://testpypi.python.org/pypi

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the quote marks around the passphrase in ~/.pypirc. The easiest way to solve this is to simply `mv ~/.pypirc ~/dot-pypirc` and run `python setup.py register`.

Comment: This doesn't use the config at all at my machine, instead it asks for user input

Answer (score 1):

Judging by a few trials,
`Server response (401): You must login to access this feature` indicates authentication failure. This happens when either:

1. your credentials are incorrect.
2. you haven't created an account at said index.
3. you are using python 3 and have a % in your password - see [here for solution](https://twitter.com/michielsikma/status/632410926621200388)

Quotes are treated as part of the password/username, so, as you've noted, you must remove them.

Comment: I consider this the best answer - if `python setup.py register -r pypitest` doesn't complain about a not found repository, it means that the .pypirc is used...

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on windows and the solution was to set the HOME environment variable to the directory where your .pypirc file is located. My .pypirc file looks like this:

```
[pypirc]
servers = pypi
[server-login]
username:<USERNAME>
password:<PASSWORD>
```

Set the env-var and restart terminal and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to the answers given above, I also faced the same issue but in my case, the reason was due to unverified account. So I suggest any new pypi account user, please go check your email and verify your account by clicking the link given in verification email. That may solve the issue.